# Fastest way to print a list of integers as a triangle from the exterior to the interior

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, time-complexity

Consider the following problem:

You receive some integer `m` and set `n=1+2+...+m`,

Now you need to print all number from `1` to `n` as a triangle from the exterior to the interior.

Example:

Input:

```
m=6
n=1+2+3+4+5+6 = 21
```

Output:

```
1
2 15
3 16 14
4 17 21 13
5 18 19 20 12
6  7  8  9 10 11
```

What's the fastest way to do this if you can use any supportive data-structure? what's the fastest way if you can't use more than `O(1)` memory?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo well, the input is `m` (which has size `log m` when encoded binary) and you need to print `O(m^2)` elements. So the running time is at least `O(2^(2t))` with `t` the size of the input.

Comment: He says O(1) memory, not time

Comment: How can you even just read a number `n` and print `n+1` using `O(1)` space given that simply storing the number requires `O(log(n))` space?

Comment: @6502 given my limited knowledge and understanding, I think `O(1)` space is generally thought of as meaning that throughout the program execution, the memory space will not exceed a minimal given amount, independent of `n`. Reading a number `n` to memory and output-ing `n+1` would be O(1) space. Reading a number `n` to memory and creating an array of `n` elements in memory would be O(n) space.

Comment: @groovy: I have the same understanding about what `O(1)` means, however to just store store an arbitrary precision integer you need `O(log(n))` space for the bits (if arbitrary precision integers are instead granted "for free" then you can store a full HD movie of arbitrary lenght in just one integer). I will assume while thinking to this problem that if you only need a limited number of arbitrary precision integers then you're still considered to be using `O(1)` in space.

Comment: @6502: I think here we assume that we have 32-bit integers, not arbitrary precision integers.

Comment: @justhalf: and you're also assuming that `n` will fit in a 32 bit integer? Then I don't understand what is the meaning of `O(...)`. If `n` is limited then anything is `O(1)`.

Comment: @6502 the numbers are just an example of an ordered set, O(1) for that matter means the solution solution doesn't depend on the size of the set

Comment: @6502: Probably this answer might help us: http://stackoverflow.com/a/487278/895932

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@groovy: I would like to add comment to your post, but I cannot (I am new to here). I think the function can be simplified as:

```
var a=0;
var atemp=0;
var edge=0;
function cal(x,y,m){
    a=Math.min((y-x),(x),(m-1-y));
    atemp=(((m+(m-3*a+1))*3*a)/2);
    edge=m-3*a;
    if(a==x){
        return atemp+1+y-a*2;
    }else if(a==m-1-y){
        return atemp+edge+x-a;
    }else{
        return atemp+edge*2-2+m-y-a;
    }
}
```

Forgive me that i am not used to give good names, and I haven't got compiler on hand so I wrote it in JS, O(1) memory for:

```
a (minimum number of the position to the bottom, left and right), 
atemp (the total number of the outer loops of triangle caused i.e. for m=4, when we print number 10, 1-9 forms the outer loop of triangle and atemp is 9), 
edge (the edge is the longest edge of the current triangle)
```

only, O(n) for time complexity for you to print all numbers out (without paddings) by nested loop sth like (not JS):

```
for(i=0;i<m;i++){ for(j=0;j<=i;j++) print cal(j,i,m); print '\n'}
```

(ps. I dun understand hashkell, but i guess your idea is somehow like this, please kindly point out if I had missed any case)

Comment: Change cal(i,j,m); -> cal(j, i,m);

Comment: This looks like a great answer. It also seems to work for any kind of m, where mine seems limited to divisible by 3 at the moment. Thank you for sharing it.

Comment: I think I see now how your idea is similar to my idea, but you found a way to describe it better and more accurately. Very nice!

Comment: @groovy: Thank you! Your answer is also great, I think if it is improved to not limited by "divisible by 3", it is already the answer

Answer (score 6):

Here's a method that uses a constant amount of memory, if you assume tail-call optimization prevents the call stack from growing unnecessarily. (code is in Python, but does not use any constructs that aren't easily ported)

```
#returns the value at the given position in the triangle of a particular size.
def valueAt(x,y,size):
    #is position out of bounds?
    if x >= size or y >= size or x > y:
        return None
    #is position on the left edge of the triangle?
    if x == 0:
        return y+1
    #is position on the bottom edge of the triangle?
    if y == size - 1:
        return x + size
    #is position on the right edge of the triangle?
    if x == y:
        return 3*size - 2 - x
    #position must lie somewhere within the triangle.
    return 3*size - 3 + valueAt(x-1, y-2, size-3)
```

This is a recursive function whose first four conditionals form the base case. If the coordinates lie out of bounds or on the edge of the triangle, we can easily find the value lying there. If the coordinates lie within the triangle's interior, we strip the big triangle like an onion, revealing a triangle three sizes smaller, and retrieve the value from that.

You can then take these values and print them by iterating through the necessary coordinates.

```
#adds spaces to the start of the string.
def pad(v, amt):
    while len(v) < amt:
        v = " " + v
    return v

def showTriangle(size):
    #figure out how many characters long each value should be, 
    #based on the length of the largest number
    maxValue = size * (size+1) / 2
    maxLength = len(str(maxValue))

    for y in range(size):
        print "\n",
        for x in range(y+1):
            val = valueAt(x,y,size)
            if val:
                print pad(str(val), maxLength),

for i in range(3, 12+1, 3):
    showTriangle(i)
    print "\n"
```

Result:

```
1
2 6
3 4 5


 1
 2 15
 3 16 14
 4 17 21 13
 5 18 19 20 12
 6  7  8  9 10 11


 1
 2 24
 3 25 23
 4 26 39 22
 5 27 40 38 21
 6 28 41 45 37 20
 7 29 42 43 44 36 19
 8 30 31 32 33 34 35 18
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17


 1
 2 33
 3 34 32
 4 35 57 31
 5 36 58 56 30
 6 37 59 72 55 29
 7 38 60 73 71 54 28
 8 39 61 74 78 70 53 27
 9 40 62 75 76 77 69 52 26
10 41 63 64 65 66 67 68 51 25
11 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 24
12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
```

Edit: if your particular system doesn't implement tail-call optimization, you can implement the iterative form yourself:

```
def valueAt(x,y,size):
    acc = 0
    while True:
        #is position out of bounds?
        if x >= size or y >= size or x > y:
            return None
        #is position on the left edge of the triangle?
        if x == 0:
            return acc + y+1
        #is position on the bottom edge of the triangle?
        if y == size - 1:
            return acc + x + size
        #is position on the right edge of the triangle?
        if x == y:
            return acc + 3*size - 2 - x
        #position must lie somewhere within the triangle.
        acc += 3*size - 3
        x-= 1
        y -= 2
        size -= 3
```

Comment: Can you explain `valueAt` in more detail ? The Tail end call in particular.

Comment: this is not tail recursive (though it's easy to fix)

Comment: what about `print valueAt(53214,64321,99999)`? I'm getting `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` using PyPy on Windows XP... My own code outputs `2777096745 (0.01 secs, 521732 bytes)`...same error with `print valueAt(53214,64321,66666)` (I'm getting 444363714 with mine)

Comment: Can you mention the time complexity of your solution?

Comment: The time complexity is `O(Nsqrt(N))`, since each element in the triangle (`O(N)`) is visited once, and for each element you might need to go to the center of the triangle in `O(sqrt(N))` time.

Comment: @groovy, yeah, `recursion depth exceeded` tends to occur for deeply recursing methods like this one. I've added an iterative version. (although, uh oh, your test cases return 2777096744 and 444184820 for me... I fear one of us has a bug.) (Edit: nevermind, it's because my coordinates begin at zero and yours begin at one. `valueAt(53213,64320,99999)` and `valueAt(53213,64320,66666)` give the outputs you described)

Comment: Python doesn't have tail call optimization so your stack will always grow even if you do make it a tail call.

Answer (score 1):

**O(1)** for memory. It prints 3 parts of triangles inserted each other. Every triangle consists of 3 lines of numbers - left vertical, horizontal on bottom and numbers placed on diagonal of right side. For any internal triangle we know the start upper left conner number which is calculated by outer one. The printing procedure consists of 3 cycles which prints parts of triangles corresponding to current row:

- print left vertical part
- print bottom part
- print diagonal numbers

It goes through all rows (i) and keeps number of triangles in t. Code in java, just change m in main to whatever you want:

public class TrianglePrint {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int m = 9;
    int t = 1;
    int p = 2;
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        if (t*2 < i && t+i < m) {
            t++;
        }
        int m1 = 0;
        for (int k = 1; k <= t && k <= i; k++) {
            System.out.print((i-(k - 1)*2 + m1)  + " ");
            m1 = getEnd(m, k); 
        }
        if (m - t + 1 == i) {
            t--;
            m1 = getEnd(m, t) + m-3*t;
            for (int k = 1; k <= p; k++) {
                System.out.print((k + m1)  + " ");
            }
            p += 3;
        }
        for (int k = t; k > 0; k--) {
            if (i < 2*k) {
                continue;
            }
            m1 = getEnd(m, k) + 2*k;
            System.out.print((m1 - i)  + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private static int getEnd(int m, int t) {
    if (t == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int e = 3*m - 3;
    for (int k = 1; k < t; k++) {
        e += 3*(m - 3*k) - 3;
    }
    return e;
}
```

Couple results:

```
1 
2 6 
3 4 5

1 
2 33 
3 34 32 
4 35 57 31 
5 36 58 56 30 
6 37 59 72 55 29 
7 38 60 73 71 54 28 
8 39 61 74 78 70 53 27 
9 40 62 75 76 77 69 52 26 
10 41 63 64 65 66 67 68 51 25 
11 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 24 
12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
```

**Edit** the code after some optimization:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            int t = Math.min(Math.min(i - j + 1, j), m - i + 1);
            int tSide = m - 3 * (t - 1);
            int end = (m + tSide + 1) * (m - tSide) / 2;
            if (t == j) {
                // vertical line
                System.out.print(end + i - t * 2 + 2 + " ");
            } else if (t == m - i + 1) {
                // bottom line
                System.out.print(end + tSide + j - t + " ");
            } else {
                // diagonal
                System.out.print(end + tSide * 2 + m - i - t + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here ye go, direct calculation of value, based on x y and m. O(1) time, O(1) space. I believe this type of method may be the fastest.

UPDATE: Pass By wrote a beautiful, succinct generalization seemingly inspired by this - see that answer.

Haskell code:

```
import Control.Monad (forM_)

f x y m 
  | rem m 3 /= 0 = error "Can only construct triangle if m is divisible by 3."
  | x > m || y > m || x < 1 || y < 1 = error "x and/or y out of bounds."
  | y == 1       = 1
  | y == m       = x - 1 + m
  | y <= lastTop = if x > div (if even y then y else y - 1) 2 + 1
                      then xOnHypotenuse
                      else xOnAltitude
  | otherwise    = let x0 = div (div (2*m) 3) 2 + 1 - (y - 2 * div m 3)
                       x1 = x0 + 2 + 3*(y - 2 * div m 3 - 1)
                   in if x < x0 
                         then xOnAltitude
                         else if x > x1 
                                 then xOnHypotenuse
                                 else xOnBase x0
 where top y = div (m*(m + 1)) 2 
             - div ((m - 3 * div y 2)*(m - 3 * div y 2 + 1)) 2
       lastTop = div (2 * m) 3
       xOnAltitude = let triangleNum = x
                         appropriateY = 2*(triangleNum - 1)
                         toAdd = y - appropriateY
                     in top appropriateY + toAdd
       xOnHypotenuse = let triangleNum = y - x + 1
                           appropriateY = 2*triangleNum 
                           toSubtract = y - appropriateY
                       in top appropriateY - toSubtract
       xOnBase baseStartingPosition = 
         let triangleNum = m - y + 1
             appropriateY = 2*(triangleNum - 1)
             baseStartingNum = top appropriateY 
                             + m - (2 + if triangleNum > 2 
                                           then 3*(triangleNum-2) 
                                           else 0) - 1
             toAdd = x - baseStartingPosition
         in baseStartingNum + toAdd

display m = 
  let maxLength = length . show $ div (m*(m + 1)) 2
      pad num = let x = length . show $ num 
                in concat (replicate (maxLength - x) " ") ++ show num
  in forM_ [1..m] (\y -> 
       forM_ [1..y] (\x -> if x == y 
                              then putStrLn (pad $ f x y m) 
                              else putStr $ (pad $ f x y m) ++ " "))
```

Output:

```
*Main> f 3 4 6
21

*Main> f 5 7 9
44

*Main> f 4 11 12
44

*Main> f 53214 64321 99999
2777096745
(0.01 secs, 518532 bytes)

*Main> display 6
 1
 2 15
 3 16 14
 4 17 21 13
 5 18 19 20 12
 6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Comment: It can't be O(1) time as in any way you print `n` numbers. could you post the running times for other inputs in order to check if it's actually linear time?

Comment: @RonTeller I believe my code is O(1) for each call to `f`, looking up the next value. Of course, to print `n` numbers, `f` would be called `n` times; in that case I would assume O(n) time, O(1) space. I already posted an example call to `f` with large numbers. I could post another, sure; which input would you like to try as a test call to `f`?

Comment: @groovy: OP is referring to the time complexity of `display` of course, not `f`, since OP wants to display the triangle. So in your case, your algorithm should be claimed as being `O(n)` instead. And `m` can be any number, not just those divisible by 3. A value of `m=1` refers to a single number, `m=2` refers to the triangle with height 2, `m=3` refers to the triangle with height 3, and so on.

Comment: @justhalf I would agree with your assessment but I like the dramatic effect :)